# Is there an Import option to allow overwriting fields with null (empty)?

Tags: contacts, import

I'm trying to do a bulk tidy-up of Address fields in CiviCRM 4.7 by exporting the data, manipulating it in a spreadsheet and re-importing it. This involves moving some values around between postal address fields, requiring some to be blanked. The Import option for Duplicate Matching can only be 'Update'. However, if I include a null value for any field it does not overwrite (blank out) an existing value, resulting in duplication. Only non-null values are considered to be updates.

Example: trying to move "121b Baker Street" from 'Supplementary Address 1' to 'Street Address' using Import/Update results in *both* these fields containing "121b Baker Street".

My problem is a more general case of the question at [Uploading null email address](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17101/uploading-null-email-address?s=2|0.2152) which refers only to blanking of email addresses.

Unless I'm missing something, I'd like to propose another option for Duplicate Matching (alongside the current Skip / Update / Fill / No duplicate checking) called '**Edit**'. It would allow the removal of existing values by overwriting with a null string but would otherwise behave in the same way as **Update**.

Comment: Hi David, I am a bit unclear, given your comment on http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17177/clear-data-from-supplemental-address-on-update. Does using the term NULL work or not?

Comment: Entering 'null' works for Text field types but not for picklist types such as State-Province. There may be others it doesn't work for.

Answer (score 1):

Although I still think the best solution is to have a new 'Edit' option for Duplicate Matching, [Clear data from supplemental address on update](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17177/clear-data-from-supplemental-address-on-update) provides a sufficient workaround for now. The use of "null" in CSV imports should be documented carefully.